# Python / Selenium ; Unable to find element by class in Internet Explorer

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer, element

I'm totally a newbie, trying to click in Internet Explorer using selenium in python.
When I can see only class = "drop_text2" from inspect element in Internet Explorer, how can I type the code to click that?

This is my script:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('drop_text2').click()
```

and inspect element in Internet Explorer:

```
<span class="drop_text2">Matrix</span>
```

Could you explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's the website you are trying to access?

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

First, wait for the page to fully load, then you may need to perform the click operation twice to make it work.

Here is a simple demo:

```
    <span class="drop_text2" onclick="myFunction()">Matrix</span>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            window.alert('You clicked me!');
        }
    </script>
```

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.ie.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


ser = Service(r"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\IEDriverServer.exe")
driver = webdriver.Ie(service = ser)
driver.get("https://localhost:44356/Index.html")
wait_time = 60 # wait for page to load
element = WebDriverWait(driver, wait_time).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,"drop_text2")))
element.click()
element.click()
```